# Glusterfs fuse client showing Stale File Handle error while copying files

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, glusterfs

I have set up my glusterfs cluster as Striped-Replicated on GCP Servers, but I am facing stale file handle error while copying files to the mounted volumes and also while doing git operations(git pull, git clone etc).

Both glusterfs server and glusterfs fuse client is using the latest version(Client-4.1.5, Server- 4.1). Please find the error messages below

**While Extracting files**

tar: basecode/wp-content/uploads/cache/wpml: Cannot mkdir: Stale file handle

**While changing ownership**

chown: cannot read directory 'www.jithin.ca/wp-content/plugins/acfml/classes': Stale file handle
chown: changing ownership of 'www.jithin.ca/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro': Stale file handle
chown: cannot read directory 'www.jithin.ca/wp-content/plugins/wp-speed-of-light/inc/pages': Stale file handle

Also am getting below error in my glusterfs client logs file(**/var/log/glusterfs/mnt-glusterfs.log**)

[2018-10-21 04:08:46.921985] W [fuse-bridge.c:1201:fuse_setattr_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 3705309: SETATTR() /Production/example.com/wp-content/cache/wpsol-cache/4bd4f0bf132901ecb17261f388864fd3 => -1 (Stale file handle)

Also, my glusterfs server is using default settings. Please help if there is any patches or fix.

Comment: Will be better if you attach your /etc/fstab here (with mount options) and show the GlusterFS configuration.

Comment: @slava
Please find the fstab entry and glusterfs process running in client below. Regarding the configuration, I am using Striped-Replicated on GCP Servers.   

`gluster1:/gluster-volume /mnt/glusterfs glusterfs defaults 0 0`

Comment: You can try to disable cache by setting `attribute-timeout` and `entry-timeout` to zero on all nodes and see what will happen. See https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mount.glusterfs/ for details. To see current mount options you can grep `/proc/mounts` - it will show some default options.

Comment: And putting the WP cache on the GlusterFS isn't a very good idea because of each node in a cluster will write to the cache folder at the same time. It may cause some problems.

Comment: @slava As we are using node cluster, is there any option to disable cache write to each node.

Comment: Left an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: don't place the WP cache on GlusterFS.

The WP on each node in a cluster will write to the cache folder at the same time and it may cause some problems. Try to point the WP to a cache directory outside GlusterFS (`/wp-cache`, for instance). I'm not very familiar with WP and can't give you an appropriate config option. Or just create a symlink inside `basecode/wp-content/uploads/` to your new cache directory.

**Second**: some people say that a striped volume works very bad and there isn't an answer why.

Try to use a distributed replicated volume instead or, maybe, a dispersed volume.

**Third**: you can use the striped volume and can play with some mount/GlusterFS options but, I think, that is a bad approach.

The first options for playing - `entry-timeout` and `attribute-timeout`, which are described here http://systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mount.glusterfs. If you set them to `0` you can disable an attribute cache. This can help you with the `Stale file handle` error but performance will be very low (in some cases). More information about `Attribute caching` here: https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs.